# Get different number of memebers for our Team site. inside the home page and inside the Site Permission menu

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, team-sites, microsoft-teams, office-365-groups

We have a modern team site inside our online tenant, where on the home page we got that we have one member as follow:

[image]

But if I access the site permission >> site members >> I will got no user as follow:

[image]

So why we have confusing results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Member in 1st image shows the members added to the **M365 group** associated with the team site.

And the 2nd image shows the membership of **SharePoint groups**.

Comment: i am not sure why this confusion !! thanks for the reply

Comment: You're welcome. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you, so that it will help other users with same doubt in future to find correct answer easily.